# Bike identification help

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have a bike that I got as a kid about 7-8 years ago which I can’t identify. All it says is “Fury” and Size 20. Serial number KS13772347. Attached image. Would love your help[image]

Comment: Welcome to this site. Your question is a decent start but you may want to have a look at https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: I see three different labels on the top tube, and "STO" or "STD" at the top of the down tube.  Please look all over the bike for words and photograph or otherwise [edit] into the question.

Answer (score 2):

I find it curious that every part of this bike is labelled with the same Fury branding.

Rims, seatpost, stem, saddle, and even the outer housing for the derailleur cable is branded as "Fury".   I bet the handlebars and grips have the same branding too.

The word "Fury" seems to occur in several brands

- GT Fury - a full-suspension MTB.   Yours is not this.
- Tiger Fury as in https://www.ebay.com/itm/312098272977  but this one lacks the excessive branding as per your example.
- "Fury" looks like a box-bike.  Here's a relevant example of modern bikes in this branding sold in Israel.   https://www.matzman-merutz.co.il/hardtail?%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D=323881&bsfilter-14085=323881

Partially based on the kickstand welded to the chainstay, I would guess this is not a high-end fancy bike.  Instead its a solid bike that was sold to ride to school, at an affordable price point while not being a complete BSO.

Ultimately - knowing more about the brand won't really do you much good other than a sense of knowledge.  Your bike looks clean and well-cared for, so congrats for looking after it.